# Как посчитать символы в windows form

Tags: c#, строки

windows forms как посчитать символы в listbox и вывести в label, чтобы каждый символ был в отдельных строках. К примеру в первой строке точки, запятые, во второй строчке слова, в третей цифры

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
            string str = (string)listBox1.Items[index];
            string nums = "";
            string chars = "";
            string symbols = "";

            char[] a = { 'выходные дни: 1, 2 января, 8 марта, 1 мая, 9 мая!' };

            foreach (char item in str)
            {
                if (char.IsDigit(item))
                {
                    nums += item;
                }
                else if (char.IsPunctuation(item))
                {
                    symbols += item;
                }
                else
                {
                    chars += item;
                }

                label1.Text += (nums);
                label2.Text += (symbols);
                label3.Text += (chars);
            }
        }
    } }
```

Вот код, не из-за чего ошибка

Comment: `как посчитать символы` ... `во второй строчке слова`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Matematic. В вашем коде несколько ошибок. 1) попытка присвоить массиву символов a непонятно что. Строка записывается в двойных кавычках. Массив символов записывается например так {'а', 'b', 'c'}. Кстати, непонятно, где этот массив используется. 2) Непонятно, как нужно обрабатывать данные в listBox1, по выделенной строке или все строки разом. Ниже привожу пример и того и другого:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1) 
    return; //строка в listBox1 не выделена, выходим

  //обработка только выделенной строки 
  int index = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
  string str = (string) listBox1.Items[index];
  string nums = "";     //цифровые символы
  string symbols = "";  //Символы пунктуации
  string chars = "";    //остальные символы

  foreach (char item in str)
  {
    if (char.IsDigit(item))
      nums += item;
    else if (char.IsPunctuation(item))
      symbols += item;
    else
      chars += item;
  }
  label1.Text = nums;
  label2.Text = symbols;
  label3.Text = chars;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //обработка всех строк
  string nums = "";     //цифровые символы
  string symbols = "";  //Символы пунктуации
  string chars = "";    //остальные символы

  foreach (object line in listBox1.Items)
  {
    foreach (char ch in (string) line)
    {
      if (char.IsDigit(ch))
        nums += ch;
      else if (char.IsPunctuation(ch))
        symbols += ch;
      else
        chars += ch;
    }
  }
  label1.Text = nums;
  label2.Text = symbols;
  label3.Text = chars;
}
```